# Oracle numbers filtering

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT distinct INCOME_LEVEL
FROM CUSTOMERS
where INCOME_LEVEL like '%-%'
```

Which returns:

[image: Query output]

I need to Leave only those levels that are in the format "999,999 - 999,999", where the number "9" means that any of the digits 0-9 are possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       income_level
FROM   customers
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( income_level, '^\d{3},\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{3},\d{3}$' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that values in that column - that contain the `-` character - *always* look like `250,000 - 299,999` (i.e. have numbers, not letters or any other characters, while there's always one space between numbers), you could even try with

```
select distinct income_level
from customers
where income_level like '%-%'
  and length(income_level) = 17
```

Comment: This will give false positives for `123 - 123,456,789`.